# Creating a progress bar for SQL query (using ADO.NET)

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, ado.net, progress

I'm trying to make a progress bar for my SQL query but don't know where to start. I have tried implementing the backgroundworker but I can't seem to get it to work.

I'm using VS 2010 .NET 4.0

```
Treinen trein = listboxVoertuigNr.SelectedItem as Treinen;
List<string> treinenIds = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in listboxVoertuigNr.SelectedItems)
{
    treinenIds.Add(item.ToString());
}

fouten = eventsEntities.Foutens;
category = eventsEntities.Category_MMAP;


IEnumerable<dynamic> FoutenResultaat = new List<dynamic>();

FoutenResultaat =
(from x in treinen
    join fout in fouten
    on x.TreinId equals fout.TreinId
    where dateStart <= fout.Datum && dateEnd >= fout.Datum
    && treinenIds.Contains(fout.Treinen.Name)
    && fout.Omschrijving.Contains(textboxFilterOmschrijving.Text)
    && fout.FoutCode.Contains(textboxFilterFout.Text)
    && fout.Module.Contains(textboxFilterModule.Text)
    orderby fout.Datum descending, fout.Time descending

    join cat in category
    on fout.FoutCode equals cat.Foutcode

    select new
    {
        Datum = fout.Datum,
        Time = fout.Time,
        FoutCode = fout.FoutCode,
        Omschrijving = fout.Omschrijving,
        Module = fout.Module.ToUpper(),
        FoutId = fout.FoutId,
        Name = x.Name,
        Category = cat.Cat_MMAP
    });

GetGraad(FoutenResultaat);
```

In GetGraad() the read data from the SQL database gets placed in a list. This is a custom list because it also gets populated with values from a excel file.

```
private void GetGraad(IEnumerable<dynamic> mijnResultaten)
{
    foreach (dynamic item in mijnResultaten)
    {
        string graad = "";
        string Toolbox = "";
        if (item.Module.Contains("_"))
            modNaam = item.Module.Split('_');
        else if (item.Module.Contains(" "))
            modNaam = item.Module.Split(' ');




        string compare = modNaam[0].Substring(0, modNaam[0].Length - 1).ToString();
        if (compare == "MPU")
        {

            var index = Properties.Settings.Default.listFoutcodeMPU.FindIndex(a => a == item.FoutCode);
            if (index == -1)
                graad = "";
            else
            {
                graad = Properties.Settings.Default.listGraadMPU[index];
                Toolbox = Properties.Settings.Default.listToolboxMPU[index];

            }



        }
        if (compare == "AAUX")
        {

            var index = Properties.Settings.Default.listFoutcodeAAUX.FindIndex(a => a == item.FoutCode);
            if (index == -1)
                graad = "";
            else
            {
                Toolbox = Properties.Settings.Default.listToolboxAAUX[index];
                graad = Properties.Settings.Default.listGraadAAUX[index];
            }


        }
        if (compare == "CTRL")
        {

            var index = Properties.Settings.Default.listFoutcodeCTRL.FindIndex(a => a == item.FoutCode);
            if (index == -1)
                graad = "";
            else
            {
                Toolbox = Properties.Settings.Default.listToolboxACTRL[index];
                graad = Properties.Settings.Default.listGraadCTRL[index];
            }
        }
        string cat = Convert.ToString(item.Category);

        if (cat == null)
            cat = "Onbeschikbaar";
        try
        {
            dataTreinFouten.Add(new FoutenMetNaam { Datum = item.Datum, FoutCode = item.FoutCode, Module = modNaam[0].ToUpper(), File = modNaam[1].ToUpper(), Name = item.Name, Omschrijving = item.Omschrijving, Time = item.Time, Graad = graad, FoutId = item.FoutId, Toolbox = Toolbox, Category = cat.ToUpper()});
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }

    }
}
```

The list is used to populate a datagrid, the class used for the list "dataTreinFouten":

```
class FoutenMetNaam
    {

        public DateTime Datum { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
        public String FoutCode { get; set; }
        public String Omschrijving { get; set; }
        public String Module { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public int FoutId { get; set; }
        public string Graad { get; set; }
        public string File { get; set; }
        public List<ExtraInfo> listInfoRondFout { get; set; }
        public bool isManueel { get; set; }
        public string Toolbox { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }

    }
```

But I can't really get the state of how far the query is already. Which means I can't update a progress bar with it current state and because the database can contain over 30.000.000 results it is quite needed.

EDIT:

I added a Entity Data Model generated from my SQL database "Events".
Code to use this:

```
private EventsEntities eventsEntities = new EventsEntities();
```

Any help or pointing in the right direction is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What part of this includes `ado.net`?  All the code looks like it's operating on in memory data (unless you're using EF)?

Comment: @CodingGorilla definitely agree

Comment: You can use a general progressbar which only indicates that the async task is working or you can use a collection which is checked how many items already have been added. but this would be the difficult part. If you dont know how much items your code will produce you can estimate the outcome. Can you provide more code with the classes you use?

Comment: I see no mention of the `BackgroundWorker` class in your code.

Comment: Didn't get close to any result from the backgroundworker. It's really confusing for me to use it because I tried implementing it from some pseudo code. Didn't feel as the right solution tho that's why asked a open question, I'm  kinda hoping there is elegant solution to this

Comment: Here is a very short example of using backgroundworker: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/83317/BackgroundWorker-and-ProgressBar-demo If you want to use backgroundworker => the '_DoWork' does the work. the `_ProgressChanged` changes your UI (progressbar, ...). In your method `GetGraad` you know how much items there are. So just report progress in your loop. the `progressbar.MaxValue` is the count of items in your list and the current value is how much items have already been processed.

Comment: So it's not possible to report progress of the linq query itself? :/ Thanks very much tho! I'm gonna try implementing it now.